# How to optimise java pattern replace

Tags: java, regex

How to optimise below regex as I have to run it over billion records

```
String test = "source[{\"name\": \"Mokole\", \"country\": \"CD\",\"location\": {\"lat\": .033333, \"lon\": -.583333}}]}\n";

String result = test.replace(" ."," 0.").replace("-.","-0.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String result = test.replaceAll("([ -])\\.","$1\\0.")
```

You can combine the `2` regexes into `1`.

Comment: won't work as . will used to match till rather than unicode . result would be like {"name":{ }0.Mokole",{ }0.country":{ }0.CD","location":{ }0."lat":{ }0.033333,{ }0.lon":{ }0..583333}}]}

Comment: @rohit - The regex looks fine. but this approach is still inefficient for scanning billions of records

Comment: agreed, i can see the difference as well when I used static pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**as I have to run it over billion records** ==> Then DON'T use `replaceAll()` which creates the pattern each time you call it.

Create a `static Pattern` using the same regex String using `Pattern.compile`. Then for each input String call `pattern.matcher(inputString)`. Then call `matcher.replaceAll()` method.

PS : Use regex mentioned by `VKS` in his answer